# Is there any class in dotNetRdf to upload the ontology in the remote server?

Tags: .net, rdf, triplestore, dotnetrdf

I am developing a .Net API and connecting it with RDF Triple Store, with the help of **dotNetRdf** library. I am successfully able to load the data and query rdf data from the remote serve. Is there any support in dotNetRdf to **load the ttl file into the remote serve**? I am trying to update the ontology in the real time, without doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the store that you are connecting to, you should be able to update the remote server using [dotNetRDF's Triple Store integration](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration). In particular you should be able to use the [UpdateGraph](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration#updategraph) method to add the triples in your TTL file (or if you want to completely overwrite the data on the server you could use the [SaveGraph](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration#savegraph) method **with caution!**).

You can see a list of the supported triple store integrations [here](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Storage-Providers). Note that it includes an integration that supports the [SPARQL Graph Store Protocol](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Storage-SPARQL-Graph-Store) which may cover you for the server you are connecting too even if it's not explicitly listed.

By the way, if you decide to use the `UpdateGraph` method you don't have to manually create the graph as is shown in the example, instead you can load your TTL file into a graph and then update the remote server using code something like this:

```cs
// Create a remote store connector. 
// The precise details will depend on which store you are connecting too.
var remoteStore = new SparqlHttpProtocolConnector(
  "http://example.org/store", // URL of the store's endpoint
  MimeTypesHelper.GetDefinitions("application/n-triples").First() // override the default use of RDF/XML for the upload
);
// Create a Graph and fill it with data we want to save
Graph g = new Graph();
g.LoadFromFile("data.ttl");

// Write triples from IGraph instance g into the named graph 
// http://example.org/graph on the remote store
remoteStore.UpdateGraph("http://example.org/graph", g.Triples, null);
```

Comment: I just tried UpdateGraph with SparqlHttpProtocolConnector but it is throwing exception: ** A HTTP error (HTTP 415 ) occurred while updating a Graph in the Store.
Store returned the following error message: Unsupported MIME type: application/rdf+xml**

Comment: If the store you are connecting to doesn't support RDF/XML then you will need to specify the mime type of a syntax that it does accept in the constructor for the SparqlHttpProtocolConnector.

Comment: I've updated the example in the main answer to show how this can be done.